# How to log if nservicebus saga is already started

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I have a saga:

```
public class MySaga : Saga<MySagaEntity>,
  IAmStartedByMessages<Message1>,
  IAmStartedByMessages<Message2> {
```

}

In general I need to see easily from logs which of the messages starts which saga.

What I need is to log something like :

> Recieved message Message1 with ... which starts a new saga
>      recieved message Message2 with ... for exsisting saga wiht Id=...

As alternatives i have following ways:
1. check if log file if that saga was not started
2. check if correlationid of saga is empty (so as it will be filled within handlers which start the saga)

```
 if (Data.CorrelationId == default_value)
      _log.DebugFormat("message starts saga CorrelationId={0}", message.CorrelationId)
```

Does anyone knew better ways for this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way in NServiceBus to get notified if a saga has been created or if a existing instance was loaded. (I've opened up a github [issue](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/1386) for further discussion)

That said if the fact that the saga was created by a given message has a business meaning you're probably better off setting a boolean flag on your saga data to record this explicitly.

```
if(Data.SagaWasStartedByAOnlineCustomer)
    Bus.Send(new VerifySomethingForOnlineCustomersCommand);
```